# How to update with multiple-table syntax?

Tags: mysql, resultset, chaining

How can I use the result of a `SELECT` to determine the fields changed in a subsequent `UPDATE`. (Effectively chaining the SELECT followed by the UPDATE together in a compound statement).

Here is what I'm trying to do in SQL:

```
SELECT id_of_record_in_table_B 
FROM table_A 
WHERE table_A.id_of_record_in_table_B = 36;

UPDATE table_B SET string_field = 'UPPERCASE' 
WHERE BINARY table_B.string_field LIKE '%lowercase' 
AND table_B.id = id_of_record_in_table_B --from the SELECT above)
```

The case sensitive match is not really relevant to the problem but I've included it because it is actually what I need to do. The problem I am trying to work out is how to "pass" the value returned from the `SELECT` into `UPDATE`.

Comment: Doesn't the first query always return only `36` (1, 2, 3, ..., 1000 or even 0 rows but all with `36`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could it in the same query such as

```
UPDATE table_B SET string_field = 'UPPERCASE' 
WHERE BINARY table_B.string_field LIKE '%lowercase' 
AND table_b.id = (SELECT id_of_record_in_table_B 
                  FROM table_A 
                  WHERE table_A.id_of_record_in_table_B = 36)
```

Comment: +1 thankyou. I particularly like this answer which uses the result of the select and does a equality comparison. I'll check this out to see how it works for me and report back.

Comment: This works if I change the = to IN `UPDATE table_B SET string_field = 'UPPERCASE' 
WHERE BINARY table_B.string_field LIKE '%lowercase' 
AND table_b.id IN (SELECT id_of_record_in_table_B 
                  FROM table_A 
                  WHERE table_A.id_of_record_in_table_B = 36)` Using = gives the result no rows affected. IN has the desired effect. Credit to you and accepted because you were close enough. Credit to: http://www.roseindia.net/sql/mysql-example/mysql-nested-select.shtml and http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/databases/mysql/threads/10744 for the 'IN'.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Assuming your inside select statement was returning a single record the `=` operator should be fine but that was a false assumption on my part i guess.

Answer (score 1):

This can be called `update with multi table` syntax thus avoiding subquery. The only problem with this syntax is you cannot use order by and limit clause

```
 UPDATE table_B as tb,table_A as ta 
 SET tb.string_field = 'UPPERCASE'  

 WHERE BINARY tb.string_field LIKE '%lowercase' 
 AND tb.id = id_of_record_in_table_B
 AND tA.id_of_record_in_table_B = 36
```

Comment: +1 thankyou! That's interesting to learn about the substitution.

Comment: I'll check this out to see how it works for me and report back.

Comment: I don't think it did sorry Angelin.  I will check again. Can you explain the need for the subsitution? The other, accepted answer did work.

Comment: ok.Iam just avoiding the subquery used in the accepted solution when it can be solved by multi table update.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a nested select statement.

```
UPDATE table_B SET string_field = 'UPPERCASE' 
WHERE BINARY table_B.string_field LIKE '%lowercase' 
AND table_B.id IN (SELECT id_of_record_in_table_B 
                   FROM table_A 
                   WHERE table_A.id_of_record_in_table_B = 36);
```

Comment: Strangely similar to @Angelin Nadar's answer.